# LESS: Unrecognised input "@import ..."

Tags: less, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

I have a really simply LESS file which for now just imports Bootstrap. I'm using `grunt` and `grunt-contrib-less@0.9.0` to compile the LESS files on save (`less@1.6.3`).

My file looks like this:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/**
 * This is the root style file for the app
 * to include styles in your html, you only need to include either:
 *  dist/styles.dev.css (for development)
 *  dist/styles.css (for production)
 */

// Libraries
@import "../lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap"

// Our own files
```

and I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run my `less:dev` task.

```
Running "less:dev" (less) task
>> ParseError: Unrecognised input in style/styles.less on line 10, column 1:
>> 9 // Libraries
>> 10 @import "../lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap"
>> 11
```

I've tried removing everything from the file except the import line and it still fails, so something weird is going on with the `@import` directive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use semi-colon after `@import`

```
@import "../lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Whoops. Good spot. It's sort of irritating that LESS didn't just say that, instead of seemingly getting picky about the "@" character.